# Random percentage symbol appended in terminal?

Tags: curl, terminal, iterm2

Let's say I have this curl request here.

```
curl -X GET https://someurlhere.com/getToken
```

All this does is call a controller method that generates some random token. The response is as follows:

```
a3f449e7-0a25-7345-4c56-283f258e0098%
```

Why is there a percentage symbol being appended at the end of the response in the terminal? Also does anyone know if this affects the actual code?

I've tried other curl requests using the cli and all of the responses coming from my API are being displayed with that "%" appended at the end.. It's very strange. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

That's a behavior of `zsh` theme.
Here is a small experiment, I got a small python script named `test.py`, and the content of it is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
sys.stdout.write('test')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

I ran it in `zsh` first, and then in `bash` and you can notice the difference below.

```
➜  /tmp ./test.py
test%                                                                                                                                                                    
➜  /tmp exec bash
bash-3.2$ ./test.py
testbash-3.2$
```